# Launching multiple lxc-net instances using a single upstart script

Tags: upstart, lxc

I would like to create two or more lxc bridges (e.g. lxcbrA, lxcbrB, etc.) using the same lxc-net.conf launched through `start lxc-net`.

I am aware of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653162/how-to-create-multiple-bridges-of-lxc), but I would rather use a single upstart script. Therefore I need the `lxc-net` service to support multiple instances.

I have read [Serge Hallyn's comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1389849/comments/5) regarding the fact that lxc-net was not supporting [instances](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#instance) one year ago.

Could someone please tell me if this feature is still not supported?